# Unable to get the checkbox in the table's column using the react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to get the checkbox in first or 4th column (to select the records in the table), tried the below code in the jscomplete online tool to run the react js components.

I tried to get the checkbox in a column for the data grid, I'm unable to come inside the if condition in the Datatable component when I check for the column name to be menuCheckBox.

Can you please help me? I'm trying the example as I'm new to react js.

Thank you very much.

[image]

```
var data = [
  {
    firstName: "Camden",
    lastName: "Hubbard",
    city: "San Francisco"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Lillian",
    lastName: "Garrison",
    city: "San Francisco"
  },
  {
    firstName: "Magee",
    lastName: "Mckinney",
    city: "Indianapolis"
  }
];

var columns = [
  { firstName: "First Name" },
  { lastName: "Last Name" },
  { city: "City" },
  { menuCheckBox: true }
];

class DataTable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var self = this;

    var order = this.props.cols.map(function(column) {
      return Object.keys(column);
    });

    var width = 100 / this.props.cols.length;

    var dataRows = this.props.rows.map(function(row, key) {
      return (
        <tr key={key}>
          {order.map(function(k) {
            // tried the below if condition to check if the column is
            //menuCheckBox to render the check box but unable to get
            if (k === "menuCheckBox") {
              return (
                <td key={k + "-" + key} width={width + "%"}>
                  <input type="checkbox" />
                </td>
              );
            }

            return (
              <td key={k + "-" + key} width={width + "%"}>
                {row[k]}
              </td>
            );
          })}
        </tr>
      );
    });

    var dataHeaders = order.map(function(k, index) {
      return (
        <th width={width + "%"} key={k} ref={k}>
          <div className="col-xs-11 row header">
            {self.props.cols[index][k]}
          </div>
        </th>
      );
    });

    return (
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>{dataHeaders}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{dataRows}</tbody>
      </table>
    );
  }
}

class DataGrid extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="table table-bordered">
        <DataTable rows={data} cols={columns} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DataGrid />, mountNode);
```

Comment: `return Object.keys(column);` this line will return an array of strings, even if you only have one key inside that object. So when you do `k === 'menuCheckbox'` you are actually comparing `['menuCheckbox'] === 'menuCheckbox'`, which will always be false.

You can change that first line I mentioned to `return Object.keys(column)[0];` to fix the problem.

Comment: Thank you Ricardo now able to see the checkboxes in the 4th column

Comment: Is there any way we can link the check box to the record or row in the data table.So that when the checkbox is clicked I need to get the values of that row. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, when you're creating your `<input />` you can map the `onChange` prop to be a function call that receives that row's info as arguments. Something like `<input type='checkbox' onChange={() => this.handleCheckboxChange(row)} />`.


You'd also need to define that function inside the class, like `handleCheckboxChange = (row) => { console.log(row.firstName, row.lastName) }`